# Make Text appears (Slide up) under an Image when you click on it

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion, jcarousel

I want a text description to appear (slide up) under an image when you click on it, and hidden(slid down) again when you when you click on it when already showing.

JAVASCRIPT

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#image img").click(function () {
            $("#image span").slideToggle();
        });
    });
</script>
```

CSS

```
#images {
    width: 275px;
    height: 200px;
}

#image div {
    display: block;
    width: 275px;
    height: 200px;
}

 #image img {
    display: block;
    width: 275px;
    height: 200px;
}

#image span {
    background: #000;
    color: #ccc;
    display: block;
    width: 265px;
    height: 40px;
    padding: 5px;
    display: none;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="images">
    <div id="image">
        <div>                
            <img src="images/test-image.png" width="224px" height="224px" />
            <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Those are the HTML above for the code I am trying to create, an example of this effect can be demonstrated when you click on any of the images on the site etchapps.com., any ideas how we can do this with JavaScript or jQuery. Or is there any other plugin that we could use to complete this.

Answer (score 2):

The real trick for this effect is to make the containing wrapper position: relative, then the wrapper inside that position: absolute with top/right/bottom set at 0. That will anchor it to the bottom of the container regardless of the height of the caption when it's visible.

Then all you need to do is slideToggle the display of the caption element. At my work we just toggled a class and used CSS transitions to cover the display, but I've tweaked our method to fall inline with your code.

Here's a [codepen example](http://codepen.io/gavmck/pen/HkvLd)

HTML

```
<div id="images">
    <div id="image">
        <div>                
            <img src="http://placekitten.com/275/200" />
            <div id="caption">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#images {
    width: 275px;
    height: 200px;
}

#image {
  position: relative;
  width: 275px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#image > div {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;


}

 #image img {
    display: block;
    width: 275px;
    height: 200px;
}

#caption {
    background: #000;
    color: #ccc;
    display: none;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#caption p {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 0;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#image img").click(function () {
        $("#caption").slideToggle();
    });
});
```

I'd also recommend switching from the divs to a figcaption and caption element for more semantic markup and probably switching out the ids for classes. You might need to update the JS to target the nearest caption rather than just any caption though.

Comment: Source: I partially wrote the website you referenced.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="images">
        <div>
            <div id="thetext" style="display:none">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</div>
            <img id="theimage" src="images/test-image.png" width="224px" height="224px" />

        </div>
</div>
</body>
    <script>

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#theimage").click(function () {
                $("#thetext").slideToggle();
            });
        });

    </script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the suggestion. I want that the text should be hidden when loaded and it should push up the image when it slides up, exactly like it is on the site etchapps.com. Currently its fixed, can you fix it? I've included the complete code

Answer (score 0):

Its solved:

Take a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/promatik/SFU4E/

I changed a bit the HTML:

```
<div id="images">
    <div id="image">
        <div class="image">         
            <img src="images/test-image.png" width="275px" height="200px" />
        </div>
        <div class="text">
            <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And CSS too:

```
#images, #image .image {
    width: 275px;
    height: 200px;
}
#image .text {
    display: none;
    background: #000;
}
#image span {
    color: #ccc;
    padding: 2px;
}
```